# Dutch Grammar in python's NLTK

Tags: python, parsing, nlp, nltk, context-free-grammar

I am working on a Dutch corpus and I want to know if NLTK has dutch grammar embedded in it so I can parse my sentences? In general does NLTK only work on English? I know that it has the Alpino dutch copora, but there is no indication that the functions (like parsing using CFGs) are made for Dutch also.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This is a response to my mail from Steven Bird one of the writers of the NLTK book:

> NLTK can work for parsing Dutch if you supply the grammar rules. 
>   Please consult the NLTK book for guidance: 
>   http://www.nltk.org/book 
>   You might be able to use the Alpino corpus in order to develop the 
>   grammar (or to train a statistical parser).  If your primary interest 
>   is obtaining parsed sentences of Dutch, I recommend that you try to 
>   find an existing parser rather than developing your own.

In the end I ended up using the Alpino parser which is really strong and written in Prolog, but I managed to port(the binary version) in python.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have a straightforward answer, but by combining information coming from the two following pages you should be able to find it out. 
[Here you can find an overview of the high-level parsing interface](http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/api/index.html) in NLTK. Parsers require a model, which if present would be listed in the page for the documentation of the [data packages that ships with nltk](http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/nltk_data/index.xml).

As you already know, the Alpino Dutch Treebank is shipped along with NLTK, so in the worst case you should be able to learn a model by yourself (the parser api also provides learning facilities).

Hope it helps somehow.